# Migração de Formulário para V10

Tags: vb.net

Boas,

tenho um formulário na v9 que é a chamado no KeyPress numa linha do Editor de Vendas e preenche uma textbox dependendo do artigo da linha.

```
Artigo.Text = EditorVendas.DocumentoVenda.Linhas(EditorVendas.LinhaActual).Artigo
```

Estou a tentar migrar este desenvolvimento para a v10 e estou com algumas dificuldades. De que referências preciso? Tenho que herdar o CustomForm? Qual a melhor forma de fazer isto? Obrigado.

Isto é como eu fazia em VBA, tinha este código no initialize do meu Form.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Artigo.Text = EditorVendas.DocumentoVenda.Linhas(EditorVendas.LinhaActual).Artigo
Descricao.Text = EditorVendas.DocumentoVenda.Linhas(EditorVendas.LinhaActual).Descricao
QuantidadeEncomenda.Text = Format(EditorVendas.DocumentoVenda.Linhas(EditorVendas.LinhaActual).Quantidade, "##,##0.00")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o que quer é na realidade algo bem diferente. Assim para ter acesso à linha selecionada no formulário de utilizador o melhor é só passar o objeto em causa e não a classe toda. No VBA todas as classes eram globais e estavam sempre acessiveis e inicializadas, o que não é o melhor em termos de boas praticas. O mesmo se passa com a forma como estava a tentar fazer. Recomendo que sempre que tem de trabalhar com partes do objeto apenas use aquilo que realmente necessita, torna o seu código mais claro e facil de manter.

```
using Primavera.Extensibility.BusinessEntities.ExtensibilityService.EventArgs;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Sales.Editors;

namespace ExtensibilityProject7.Sales
{
    public class UiEditorVendas : EditorVendas
    {
        public override void TeclaPressionada(int KeyCode, int Shift, ExtensibilityEventArgs e)
        {

            PriCustomForm1 form = new PriCustomForm1();

            // Passa a linha actual
            form.LinhaDoc = this.DocumentoVenda.Linhas.GetEdita(this.LinhaActual);
        }
    }
}
```

No seu formulário deve ter algo assim.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Primavera.Extensibility.BusinessEntities;
using Primavera.Extensibility.CustomForm;

namespace ExtensibilityProject7.Sales
{
    public partial class PriCustomForm1 : CustomForm
    {
        public VndBE100.VndBELinhaDocumentoVenda LinhaDoc { get; set; }

        public PriCustomForm1()
        {
            string artigo = LinhaDoc.Artigo;
            string descricao = LinhaDoc.Descricao;
            double quantidadeEncomenda = LinhaDoc.Quantidade;

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Também já tinha tentado essa hipótese, mas depois de aberto o editor de vendas, ao abrir o meu formulário, dá-me o erro "Não é possível executar a vinculação de runtime numa referência nula". Lembrando que tenho o assembly resolver na minha aplicação. Obrigado

Comment: @BrunoGomes tem um resposta mais atualizada

Comment: Assim já funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bruno, antes de mais começe por criar um projeto de PEX com recurso à extensão para o VS disponivel mo marketplace, e que poder ser acedida por aqui no [developers network](https://developers.primaverabss.com/_v10/#comunidade). Isto vai garantir sempre todas as referencias necessárias ao projeto.

Quanto ao seu código, basta fazer isto:

```
using Primavera.Extensibility.BusinessEntities.ExtensibilityService.EventArgs;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Sales.Editors;

namespace ExtensibilityProject7.Sales
{
    public class UiEditorVendas : EditorVendas
    {
        public override void TeclaPressionada(int KeyCode, int Shift, ExtensibilityEventArgs e)
        {
            string artigo = this.DocumentoVenda.Linhas.GetEdita(this.LinhaActual).Artigo; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Boas Sérgio, mas neste caso eu quero conseguir interagir diretamente com o Editor de Vendas a partir de um formulário meu, sem ter de o abrir, por exemplo. Como consigo fazer isso nesta versão?

Comment: No editor entenda-se interface não é possivel. Só é possivel manipular o objecto associado ao documento de venda. Mas não esta a questão que colocou.

Comment: Posso não ter colocado corretamente a questão. Mas como faço para manipular o objeto associado ao documento de venda?

Comment: Está disponivel no contexto `this.DocumentoVenda`. Pos isso se herdares do `EditorVendas` tens lá acesso aos objetos.

Comment: Já tinha tentado fazer isso, mas não consigo herdar o EditorVendas... https://imgur.com/aoTynTh

Comment: Como disse no site em `https://developers.primaverabss.com/_v10/#comunidade` dá acesso à extensão para o visual studio que coloca lá as referencias todas necessárias. Recomendo que o instale.

Comment: Mas eu já tenho a extensão instalada, e mesmo assim não consigo. Numa classe funciona perfeitamente, num form é que não...

Comment: Mas isso não dá, são objetos diferentes, como se pode ver pelo proprio erro que o VS está a dar na imagem partilhada.

Comment: Mas isto era possível na V9. Na V10 já não é?

Comment: Bruno não sei então o que quer fazer, mas na v9 isso não existia, isto é, não existe herança. É melhor colocar outra questão mais detalhada e com código que ajude.

Comment: Não me estou a referir à herança, mas sim à possibilidade de, por exemplo, no Load do meu form, carregar informação de um documento de venda.

Comment: Sérgio, adicionei o código na questão.